# memtest86 taking a lot of time

Tags: memory, memtest86+, ddr, memtest

I'm new to using memtest; my problem is that I've been running memtest86 now for about 13hrs and its only 90% in pass 2/4 ??

It's currently showing 25 errors. My question is: Is this in some way normal? I've been reading about people running 10-20 passes? In this rate that would take a lifetime.

About the errors: Do errors mean that there IS something wrong with the memory or that it could be?

I'm using 32gb (4x8gb) HyperX 2666mhz and a maximus ranger motherboard (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VII_RANGER/)

Kind regards, Emil

Comment: The errors are likely slowing it done.  Honestly given you have errors means you already side identified a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RAM has failed, a single error is enough to warrant ending the test as it has done it's job.

From here you can remove sticks and put them in individually to test them separately, in order to identify the failed stick(s).

If the RAM you're currently using is paired with another stick(s) of the same age, it may be worth replacing them together, as it's possible they may also show signs of failure, although this by no means a necessity, and in your situation is probably a lot more cost effective to identify which one(s) are actually at fault.

I wouldn't bother waiting for any more passes, there's a definite problem and further tests in the same configuration aren't necessary.

Comment: Yeah it failed in test 13 in all passes. From what ive read the thing test 13 tests doesnt occur in normal home use but either way ill go ahead and replace them and hope for stable ones.

Answer (score -2):

13 hours seems quite right, prepare for **test** 3 and 4 to take REALLY long.

But in fact, you can already cancel it: There is something wrong with your memory subsystem, not necessarily the RAM itself, but most often so.

Try reseating the DIMMs and running it again, but don't be too hopeful - in case the errors reappear in a second run bisect the error: Run memtest86 with DIMMs 1&2, 3&4 and 1&3 - this will tell you waht you need to replace.

**EDIT:** renamed 'pass' with 'test' in the first sentence to accuratly reflect current memtest86 nomenclature

Comment: Subsequent passes won't take longer because they are all identical, memtest86[+] loops until interrupted.

Comment: @gronostaj memtest86 is organized into different "passes", that do different things. Pass 3 and 4 take longer than others, because they do the most intensive work (as opposed to e.g. pass 1, which is the fastest). So this is not about subsequent running of the same job, but about different jobs as defined in memtest86

Comment: Citation needed.  I could easily believe that different tests (or maybe "phases?) take longer.  However, my understanding is that a "pass" is a completion of all the tests.  I'd be interested in seeing documentation suggest otherwise.  So if some tests run slower, they would likely do so on every pass.  (Although, if there is bad hardware, results can potentially be much less predictable.)

Comment: @TOOGAM Citation by running memtest86.

Comment: @EugenRieck I tried to test it in a VM, but results appear to be rather random... I'll run some tests on real hardware later. However we should already note that indeed in memtest's nomenclature a *pass* is composed of several *tests* and it suggests that testing is complete after first pass.

Comment: @gronostaj - the VM randomness is to be expected: The cache switching done by memtest86 is not emulated. I stand corrected concerning "Test" vs. "Pass" and will update the answer accordingly. It's been quite some time since I was on hardware without a BMC, so the memtest86 UI might have changed quite significantly.